# cannot get bitmap from google profile picture url

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have an app in which I am trying to retrieve the image from a link that I get through google integration. However, whenever i try to get the pic into a bitmap it always gives me an error. Code and the error are below :

code:

```
if (google_user_gallery_pic.isEmpty() == true)
{
    if (google_user_pic.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        onPost = null;
        onPost2 = null;
        onPost = getBitmapFromURL(google_user_pic);
        onPost2 = onPost2.createScaledBitmap(onPost, 100, 100, false);
    }

    else
    {
        onPost = null;
        onPost2 = null;
        onPost = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(google_user_gallery_pic);
        if (onPost == null)
        {
            onPost2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.the_smallperson);
        }

        else
        {
            onPost2 = onPost2.createScaledBitmap(onPost, 100, 100, false);
        }
    }
}

else
{
    onPost = null;
    onPost2 = null;
    onPost = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(google_user_gallery_pic);
    if (onPost == null)
    {
        onPost2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.the_smallperson);
        //onPost2 = onPost2.createScaledBitmap(onPost, 100, 100, false);
    }

    else
    {
        onPost2 = onPost2.createScaledBitmap(onPost, 100, 100, false);
    }
}
```

the error:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/lh3.googleusercontent.com/-HW5Tk9h1V2I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADA8/7UbMeHbyFLM/photo.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

the url:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-HW5Tk9h1V2I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADA8/7UbMeHbyFLM/photo.jpg
```

This url works on one page but doesnt work on another. Both pages are fragment activities. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why not using picasso?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 idk how to use that

Comment: did you save the bitmap in file...and trying to open it?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 actually i store it in a database and retrieve it from there. so you can say, yes

Comment: if you are testing on marsmallow (Sdk >23) you need runtime permission to save and retreive file...also in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: done it man ...

Comment: still not works ?

Comment: nope ... idk what the problem is

Comment: what specific line the exception thrown?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 idk exactly, because its not actually an error which causes the app to crash .... its just an exception ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing the if and else conditions to something like this:

```
if (google_user_gallery_pic.isEmpty() == false)
{
    if (google_user_pic.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        onPost = null;
        onPost2 = null;
        onPost = getBitmapFromURL(google_user_pic);
        onPost2 = onPost2.createScaledBitmap(onPost, 100, 100, false);
    }

    else
    {
        onPost = null;
        onPost2 = null;
        onPost = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(google_user_gallery_pic);
        if (onPost == null)
        {
            onPost2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.the_smallperson);
        }

        else
        {
            onPost2 = onPost2.createScaledBitmap(onPost, 100, 100, false);
        }
    }
}

else
{
    onPost = null;
    onPost2 = null;
    onPost = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(google_user_gallery_pic);
    if (onPost == null)
    {
        onPost2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.the_smallperson);
        //onPost2 = onPost2.createScaledBitmap(onPost, 100, 100, false);
    }

    else
    {
        onPost2 = onPost2.createScaledBitmap(onPost, 100, 100, false);
    }
}
```

Because given the permissions and anything else rather than this code snippet, there was nothing wrong in it other than this

Answer (score 1):

Try using picasso to load image bitmap from URL.

```
 private Target mTarget;   //declare variable

void loadImage(Context context, String url) {

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    mTarget = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
            //Do something on the bitmap
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //set the bitmap
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    };

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .into(mTarget);
            ..error(R.drawable.the_smallperson) // will be displayed if the image cannot be loaded
}
```

in gradle add:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: yes you need to import it..after you add the gradle

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the logic because it did work for some time when i reversed the conditions, as per Saim's answer ...

Comment: it didnt actually give me the actual output ofcourse, but it worked for some time